# Java-Swing and Windows text size : fix the size of components

Tags: java, windows, swing, text-size

When my-application users increase 'windows texte size' to 150% ([picture](http://img.technospot.net/windows-7-display.png)), all components(text, buttons..) grow and application exceeds screen size.

Do you have a suggestion to make GUI fixed(or all component svisible) with every windows text size (100%, 125%, 150%)?

Thanks.
PS:I use JGoodies

Comment: Your question contains too little about your application. Its too difficult to help.

Comment: Oh. I am sorry. Actually I did not understand your problem. I am not very used to in Windows and I thought the screenshot you gave is of your application. Your question is not that less informative as I thought.

Comment: Your best bet is todesign your application on Windows with 150% size: if your screens fit there, they will fit with other font settings. Then let LayoutManager decide how to use the extra available space (this is something JGoodies FormLayout already does).

Comment: Thank you. Of course I think i am going to do that. I understand more and more why we went to the "full-web" in major Enterprise applications ...

Answer (score 2):

use proper layout manager and dont `setPreferredSize()/setSize()` etc to component like button, panel window/dialog and use `pack()` window/dialog.

Comment: Your answer isn't very clear or readable. Please consider rewording it and making it more readable.